# Hover item, get under it a box in the width of the item text

Tags: css

For a navigation, I need the following:

- If you hover an item, then under it, a box should appear. (Already
  works in my example.)
- The box should have the same width like the item text, for example "One". (Does not work
  yet.)

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  /* width: fit-content; ––– Does not work */
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to try it with `width: fit-content;`, but it does not work.

How is it possible to do that? Would be very happy for help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit-content` should be added to li

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;/*dont forget this */
}

li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`::after` is a pseudo-element, so it needs to have a set width on the element creating it in order to work with percentages (in this case `width: 100%;`). Also, remove the `position: absolute;`.

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li{
  width: 100px;
}

li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```